# Error : Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt

I am getting this could not resolve issue. I have been on an open network from last two months after fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04. I have just shifted in a LAN with proxy. I have done every settings including updating the /etc/resolv.conf file and have looked at other solutions of these types. None is working.

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                     
Could not resolve 'download.sublimetext.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                
Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/leaeasy/dde/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'download.sublimetext.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Which VPN are you using? Can you find a configuration for it in network manager's Edit Connection dialog? If it's openvpn, is it actually installed? I've heard of it showing up without being installed.

Comment: @Joe I don't see a reference to a VPN?  LAN with Proxy is not a VPN

Comment: no vpn is being used.

Comment: Does name resolution work on your machine? Can you ping internet address? Try "dig www.google.com" and "ping www.google.com" and let us know your result. I think there is no problem with archive.ubuntu.com, you probably just have a general problem accessing the internet. PS: If you configured a proxy, post your apt configuration for this proxy.

Comment: Results of dig and ping : dig www.google.com
bash: dig: command not found
yo@yo-hp-pavilion-notebook:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known

Comment: my apt configuration is fine : it has it's configuration in these format only. http::username:passwd@202.141.80.24:3128

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your host is behind a proxy server.

Add the following line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. If the file doesn't exist create one.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Replace *yourproxyaddress* and *proxyport* appropriately.

Or, if authentication is required:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pwd@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Comment: Assuming that missing proxy creds are, in fact, the OP's problem, this answer is corect/fine. But if the current user's environment already has the `http[s]_proxy` vars set, an alternative is to run `sudo -E apt install <whatever>`. (The `-E` switch runs the command with the current user's env vars set.) I generally have an easier time remembering to tack on `-E` than dredging up the somewhat awkward syntax used to set an APT proxy in `/etc/apt`. (And such changes should nowadays be placed in a separate file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, anyway.)